# assembly-Segfault when spawning a shell

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, shellcode

I'm having some issues with a small program to spawn a shell. Right now, my program segfaults when trying to modify the string on the line `movb $0,7(%ebx)`
I think the issue is that I'm trying to modify code in the text segment, and not on the stack. I thought ebx, being the base pointer for the stack, that I should be able to modify it there. What is wrong with that line? my code is below. Thanks

```
jmp payload+0x28

payload:
movl $0xb,%eax
popl %ebx
movb $0,7(%ebx)
movl %ebx,0x8(%ebx)
movl $0x0,0xc(%ebx)
leal 0x8(%ebx),%ecx
leal 0xc(%ebx),%edx
int $0x80
movl $1,%eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
call payload
.string "/bin/sh"
```

Comment: what is targetting `jmp payload+0x28`? Why don't you use another label like `payload:`? Do you expect us to calculate it from head? You don't even show how you build it, with which tools and command line options, maybe you even produce 64b machine code by accident.. anyway, let's guess it's jumping on the `call` instruction, then the `ebx` points to the code segment, on the first letter/byte of that string (`'/'`). Why do you think it points to stack? :-o btw: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: I assumed it wouldn't be necessary to add the entire program including main. I'm not clear on what you mean by "what is targetting jmp payload+0x28", it jumps to call payload, no I don't expect you to calculate anything by head. Is it necessary to state I used gcc to compile the program? If I knew that the program segfaults on a specific line, used gdb, I would assume that meant I did attempt to debug, I believe that was a lazy remark. I'm just trying to understand why I can't make modify the 'ebx' register.

Comment: Never assume it isn't necessary to show your entire program. When someone doesn't know what the problem is, they typically also don't know what it isn't. Are you placing the code shown on the stack before executing it?

Comment: I can definitely agree with that statement, I believe this is one of those cases. I don't think I am. I was under the impression that I could spawn a shell just through assembly code. Googling what you said about placing the code on the stack before executing came up with an example from the paper "Smashing the stack for fun and profit". Their example shows writing a C program and placing all of this assembly within a global array. I thought I could do this all within a .s file, but that seems like it makes sense if I have to place my assembly within a C file. Is that what you meant?

Comment: about labels: from your post I have no idea where `payload+0x28` is located, unless I would compile it myself, and count 0x28 bytes after `payload:` label. From the exploit-like code it's likely the `call` is the target, but I'm too lazy to verify, you should either post meaningful disassembly including addresses, so one can easily see +0x28, or post valid source. (if you have `payload+0x28` in source, you are asking for trouble, then just a minor modification of code between will make the jump out of sync).

Comment: about gcc: stating compiler, compile options, and how you execute the binary on which kind of host platform is absolutely vital in assembly, to both judge whether it's correct, and eventually to replicate your problem ([MCVE]). If you are for example trying to run this piece of assembly in linux-for-windows under win10, it will never work, because it doesn't support 32b linux ABI (just example), etc... there's million of reasons why seemingly valid code may fail, either on some "stupid" detail, or even on something principally wrong which will require almost whole code rewrite.

Comment: about debugging: if you did debug, why do you think `ebx` points to stack memory, as it should be either completely different from `esp` (if you are in normal `.text` segment), or you really injected it into stack, then pointing these things out, where it did land, is another vital information to judge why it doesn't work. There's like once per 1-2 weeks question about why `movb $0,(..somewhere_into_string..)` segfaults, usually because the string is in the code segment and the OP is running exploit code as ordinary asm app.

Comment: anyway, to give you answer with as much fidelity, as your question provides, the answer would be: "There's not much wrong with `movb $0,7(%ebx)`, it works exactly as it *should*. Fix your other problems to make it work as you *want*." (Although it contains zero byte in the opcode, so it's not very "exploit-compatible", ruining this exploit code in case it will be deployed as C-string, but judging by your current problems you don't need to worry about that yet, you would have to first learn some asm basics to handle at least ordinary application code, then you can focus on exploit-code nuances)

Comment: I think that piece of "There's like once per 1-2 weeks question about why movb $0,(..somewhere_into_string..) segfaults, usually because the string is in the code segment and the OP is running exploit code as ordinary asm app", answers my question. I was under the assumption that it could be ran as an ordinary asm app.

Comment: And to add to that, from most of the answers I've seen here people have just given chunks of assembly code and that's been an accepted answer. I was hoping for more of an explanation or resources explaining why than copy and pasting code.Just trying to learn.

Comment: If you will follow the duplicate, there's a suggestion how to bend ordinary app to have code segment writeable. Which is sort of cheat, as common app will usually not use such setting (it would made all the memory-overwrite bugs targetting code suddenly to work, and instead of seg-fault they would just subtly modify the machine code, making it crash much later, or produce very weird behaviour and bugs, not making any sense, and very difficult to debug). But if you are working on small exploit code, it's valid idea to simplify the build+execution+debugging, instead of stack to use +w on `.text`

Comment: Also you may try to read your original post as if you never seen it, or worked on your problem before, and try to follow my rants, if you can see how it is incomplete and difficult to reproduce, making it just a guess game, which exact variant of that problem you did hit. Such exercise may give you further experience and insight, what you have to study about more, as it is not that obvious/granted as you thought before. (but basically you are trying to learn so many things at the same time, that just expect some friction and push hard, will take some time and dedication, but you can do it).

Comment: @user406955: there are quite a lot of bad code-only answers on SO, but also quite a lot of good answers that explain the problem as well as showing the solution.  Especially in the assembly-language tags, most people that take the trouble to find existing duplicates for you will look for one with a *good* answer.  See also the FAQ section in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, there are links to many Q&As with explanations.